# How to import a package from another folder?

Tags: java, package

> I am trying to save all packages in lib/Package folder and my main program where i want to >import it is save in src file as shown in picture. How could i import Add package to perform
> task. I m new in java.
> the path of package is C:\Users\user_name\Documents\GitHub\NewProjectA\lib\packages
> the path of main file is C:\Users\sumit\Documents\GitHub\NewProjectA\src
> please help me to understand it in a easy way. That how can i import a package in the main

[image]

Comment: here ?? mark is use to ask for help

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create package under your src folder or create a diffrent moduke and import it

Answer (score -1):

You should move the lib folder into the src folder. All code in a java project will be under the src file. Therefore the Source name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: don't be toxic, i was just doing a review queue. i don't get to choose what the message says, it's automatic.